# Oracle - Group calls closed by week per analyst SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not hugely experienced in SQL but need to generate some tabular, grouped results by weeks.  I've set up an ODBC connection to our oracle database and want to extract this data for some pivot charts. At the moment I have to manually extract this data week by week through SupportWorks reports and I want to automate it.

I can't apparently add an image to show you what it should look like but effectively a line per analyst covering all the weeks of the year with the number of calls they have closed by week.

So I guess I want to count the number of calls per analyst per week since the beginning of the year so I have a table for all my analysts.

I suppose there are only really 2 relevant fields but I can't work out how to do the whole week by week thing, with extra rows per analyst,  bearing in mind my KPI week is Saturday to Monday.  If there is a system defined week I could move my KPI dates to adjust to that?

closedate   (Date call was closed)

closedby    (who closed the call)

I'd be hugely grateful for some assistance here if possible.

I've tried to research a solution but can't quite find something to help me.

Here is some example SQL that focuses on the calls in question.  Some has been changed to anonymise it.

- select closedate, closedby from opencall where
- ((status > 15 OR status = 6)
- and closedby in ('analyst1','analyst2','analyst3', 'analyst4','analyst5','analyst6','analyst7')
- AND trunc(to_date(substr(closedate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-OCT-14' AND '31-DEC-14')
- order by closedate

I've put this in a list above as the formatting in this window is a bit 1990's.

So the above code would extract about 1300 rows of call information that I then want have columns by week, and rows by analyst with the number of calls each of them has closed in that week.

I tried doing this with the code sample kindly provided by a commenter but still get an error.

select to_number(to_char(closedate, 'IW')) as "Week number"

```
      ,closedby as "Closed by"

      ,count(closedate) as "Calls closed"

from  opencall

where
```

((status > 15 OR status = 6)

and closedby in ('analyst1','analyst2','analyst3', 'analyst4','analyst5','analyst6','analyst7')

AND trunc(to_date(substr(closedate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-OCT-14' AND '31-DEC-14')

Comment: Can you `DESCRIBE` the relevant table or tables?

Comment: Actually I misread the question, the column names are there anyway, but thanks. :)

Comment: The query should be easy if you don't mind moving your KPI week. If you prefer Sat-Mon it's probably more awkward, but could certainly be done.

Comment: At the moment my KPI week is from Sunday to Saturday but that is only because that is how Support Works reporting works in its week ranges.  I have no problem being flexible in my KPI week reporting if I can get a solution to the above.  Cheers

Comment: Tell more about the `closedate` column. It looks as though it's `varchar2` with the first 10 characters holding the date in the format `'DD-MM-YYYY'`. Is that correct?

Comment: Closed date data looks like this:  30/10/2014 16:12:30  I'm only interested in the data itself and not the time hence my trunc

Comment: Is `closeddate` definitely stored as a `DATE` datatype and not as a  `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: Looks like it must be stored as a varchar2 as that is the DATATYPE on the COLUMN detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with closed_calls as
 (select to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 'IW')) as week_number
        ,closedby 
  from   opencall 
  where  ((status > 15 or status = 6)
  and    closedby in ('analyst1','analyst2','analyst3', 'analyst4','analyst5','analyst6','analyst7')
  and    trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) between '01-OCT-14' and '31-DEC-14'))
select week_number as "Week number"
      ,closedby as "Closed by"
      ,count(closedby) as "Calls closed"
from   closed_calls
group by week_number
        ,closedby
order by week_number desc
        ,closedby asc;
```

The date is stored as a string, so must first be converted to a date datatype:

```
to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Then you can truncate it to get rid of the time portion, then extract the week number.

If you don't mind moving your KPI week, this should be easy enough. You can convert a date to a week number using a format mask. The format mask will convert to a varchar2 string first, so you might perform a second conversion to number for sorting.

```
to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 'WW'))
```

will return the week number, starting from the 1st day of the year.

```
to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 'IW'))
```

will return the ISO standard week number, which starts from the first Monday of the year.

Your full query would look something like this:

```
select to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 'IW')) as "Week number"
      ,closedby as "Closed by"
      ,count(closeddate) as "Calls closed"
from   your_table
where  ...
group by to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), 'IW'))
        ,closedby
```

EDIT: I might be overthinking the KPI week. If your week starts on Sunday, I think you should be able to get what you need by simply adding 1 day to your closeddate, ie:

```
select to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1), 'IW')) as "Week number"
      ,closedby as "Closed by"
      ,count(closeddate) as "Calls closed"
from   your_table
where  ...
group by to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(closedate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1), 'IW'))
        ,closedby
```

Test that before you take my word for it though!

If you're still getting conversion errors, it's possible there's a dodgy value in `closedate` which doesn't match the format mask. That's the problem with storing dates as `varchar2`, you miss out on an easy way to validate the data as it goes into the database.

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 26

Comment: Oops, forgot the `group by`, hold on.

Comment: I tried using your code with my code and got the error above.  I can't put the code in these comment fields as it loses all the formatting.  I'll see what I can do about reposting it.  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: OK let me give it a go ;o)

Comment: Getting an error still  ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: select to_number(to_char(closedate, 'IW')) as "Week number"
          ,closedby as "Closed by"
          ,count(closedate) as "Calls closed"
    from  opencall
    where   
((status > 15 OR status = 6) 
and closedby in ('analyst1','analyst2','analyst3', 'analyst4','analyst5','analyst6','analyst7')
AND trunc(to_date(substr(closedate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-OCT-14' AND '31-DEC-14')
group by to_number(to_char(closedate, 'IW'))
        ,closedby

Comment: CLOSEDATE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) It seems to be nullable, if that means anything

Comment: Ok, it's `VARCHAR2`. That's pretty much always a pain when dates are stored as strings rather than actual dates.

Comment: By jove I think you've got it.  I'll need to work through the data but I think this is practically giving me what I need or at least a very good starting point to continue working on this.  Thanks so much for your help.

How would I order the output by week number in descending order as the week is a contrived number?  At the moment its grouped by week which is brilliant but they weeks are not in a sequential order

Comment: I've added a query at the top of my answer which sorts the results by week descending and analyst ascending. I used a common table expression to tidy it up a bit, and prevent having to do all the conversions on `closedate` in the each of the `select`, `group by` and `order by` clauses.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You have been incredibly helpful